# How to Dynamically Modify Physics Body Attribute of an Aframe Element

Tags: javascript, aframe

The following code works wonderfully with aframe and the [aframe physics library](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system).

```
      <a-box       
          id="kek"
          body="type: static; mass: 5; shape: none;"
          shape__main="shape: cylinder;
                       height: 2;
                       radiusTop: 2;
                       radiusBottom: 2;">
      </a-box>
```

However, when I attempt to replicate the same element dynamically the results are not as expected.

```
let box = document.createElement('a-box');
box.setAttribute('body', 'type: static; mass: 5; shape: none;');
box.setAttribute('shape_main', 'shape: cylinder; height: 2; radiusTop: 2; radiusBottom: 2');
ascene.appendChild(box);
```

The a-box element does not show any physics frame in debug mode. I inspected the HTML and it seems that the 'body' attribute does not update properly. An image of the two elements in the HTML is linked here (top element is dynamically created, bottom element is defined in HTML):

[Image of the HTML elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ3n0.png)

I can post more code if this is insufficient, but I believe I am overlooking something.

Comment: It seems like you forgot an underscore (shape_main instead of shape__main) in your setAttribute call.

Comment: I guess that's what copy and paste is for. I'm a bit embarrassed but that was the problem! Thank you!